# printf() doesn't show up first

Tags: c, printf

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SPITZE          1
#define GUT             2
#define BEFRIEDIGEND    3
#define AUSREICHEND     4
#define DURCHGEFALLEN   5
#define JA              1
#define NEIN            0

int main (void)
{

    unsigned int note, bestanden;

    printf ("\nGeben Sie bitte eine Note (1-5) ein: ");
    scanf ("%u", &note);

    if (note == SPITZE)
        bestanden = JA;
    else if (note == GUT)
        bestanden = JA;
    else if (note == BEFRIEDIGEND)
        bestanden = JA;
    else if (note == AUSREICHEND)
        bestanden = JA;
    else
        bestanden = NEIN;

    bestanden ? printf ("\nOK!,") : printf( "\nNICHT bestanden");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Console output]

So the console doesn't even print out the text first `printf ("\nGeben Sie bitte eine Note (1-5) ein: ");` . The text doesnt show up, until I enter a Number and then it prints out the "printf & the result" directly.

How do I get it to printf the line to see it ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fflush()` after `printf()`:
Its purpose is to clear (or flush) the output buffer and move the buffered data to console (in case of `stdout`) or disk (in case of file output stream).

Comment: May I have an example, since I tried it and it still doesn't work. I wanna  see if i got it correct

Answer (score 2):

When using functions that print to `stdout` like `printf`, on some systems you might need to "flush" the buffer in order to make the items appear on screen.

This is typically done by adding a `\n` at the end of each `printf`, but you can also do it explicitly with a call to `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: `\n` in this case is not good as he wants to have cursor just past the prompt

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is buffered so you should flush it before the `scanf`